# Getting InterruptedException when deploying JMS app in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jms, activemq-artemis

My war file is deployed in a JBoss server and it connects to the queue in another machine. While deploying the war file I'm getting this exception:

```
2022-12-21 11:28:02,749 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (Thread-254 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) AMQ154004: Failed to deliver message: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQMessageHandler.onMessage(ActiveMQMessageHandler.java:330)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1031)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1154)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)

2022-12-21 11:28:02,778 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-254 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQInterruptedException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:430)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:358)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.sessionStop(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:473)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.stop(ClientSessionImpl.java:1096)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.stop(ClientSessionImpl.java:1085)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.rollback(ClientSessionImpl.java:989)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.rollback(ClientSessionImpl.java:972)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQMessageHandler.onMessage(ActiveMQMessageHandler.java:385)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1031)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1154)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2151)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:428)
    ... 16 more
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: My client ActiveMQ Artemis  jar version is 2.19.1

Comment: The line numbers in the stack-trace don't match 2.19.1. For example, the `NullPointerException` is being thrown from line 330 of `ActiveMQMessageHandler.java`, but in 2.19.1 that line is a [logging statement](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.19.1/artemis-ra/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/ra/inflow/ActiveMQMessageHandler.java#L330) which is basically exactly the same as a logging statement 20 lines before that.

Comment: The next entry in the stack-trace is from line 1031 of `ClientConsumerImpl.java` which should be calling  `onMessage` but [it's not](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.19.1/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/client/impl/ClientConsumerImpl.java#L1031). It's calling the `discardBody` method instead.

Comment: I can't investigate further without an accurate indication of which version of ActiveMQ Artemis you're using.